# How can I get the HTML from a web page in Bada?

Tags: load, get, html, bada

I don't know what other details I should provide. But I am very disoriented. I am not a web developer so I don't know what classes to use. It's not like I can tell the difference between HttpResponse, HttpHeader, HttpSession, HttpTransaction etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Making HTTP Requests](http://dpimg.ospos.net/contents/docs/resources/com.samsung.bada.devguide.help/html/basic_bada_features/network/making_HTTP_req.htm) and [Receiving HTTP Responses](http://dpimg.ospos.net/contents/docs/resources/com.samsung.bada.devguide.help/html/basic_bada_features/network/receiving_HTTP_res.htm).

The code in the second doc would normally go in a IHttpTransactionEventListener::OnTransactionCompleted method.

The HTML you are seeking should then be the return value of HttpResponse::ReadBodyN.